# Confusion with Ruby commandline switch "-p"

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

`-p` ==> assume loop like -n but print line also like sed.

Now I tried below to see how it works :

```
@ubuntu:~$ ruby -p
hi #<~~ pressed on ENTER
   # nothing printed baack 
\t
-:5: syntax error, unexpected $undefined, expecting $end
@ubuntu:~$
```

In the above after typing "hi", when I press 'ENTER' got ***blank line*** as above. I thought it would give a output as ***hi***.

Now I tried it a bit different way :

```
@ubuntu:~$ ruby -p -e '"hi"'
hi  #<~~ pressed on ENTER
hi
ttt #<~~ pressed on ENTER
ttt
\t  #<~~ pressed on ENTER
\t
EOF #<~~ pressed on ENTER
EOF
```

But here it seems `-p` worked as expected. But the `Loop` falls into an infinite `Loop`. I tried `EOF` to finish this loop, but that not happened,rather it was also printed out.

Can anyone help me to understand why these difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-p` will do:

```
- Read a line from input
- Pass the input to the code
- If the code executes successfully, print the input
```

If you don't provide a file name or a `-e` in command line, it will just consume standard input without executing anything. `-p` does not print because no code is provided.

When you just put `-pe '"hi"'`, it will generate a `hi` string every time you input a line (but it is in the memory but no output) and print as `-p` indicated.

`EOF` you put is not an EOF indicator. It is a string `"EOF"`. If you want to send an EOF signal to ruby, press `Ctrl+Z` and Enter

Comment: Yes! your answer makes sense. `Ctrl+Z` I had already tried and it breaks the Loop, but forgot to update it here. But the `-p` explanation is perfect ,which I just stopped wondering after reading your answer. I had also guessed it, but didn't get any source to prove me guess :) Could you also share with me the source which helps you to answer this confidently?

Answer (score 0):

You first experiment failed because, without a program, the interpreter will read standard input until EOF. So, you are in the confusing situation of *first* needing to input a program from standard input, then a ^D or whatever EOF is on your console, and *then* your program would start and it would read standard input *again* to implement the canned loop.

In the second case, you at least avoid the dual standard-input snarf. And it's not exactly an infinite loop, when you type an EOF it will finish.